# how to determine xpaths for ajax element

Tags: selenium-rc

I need to detemine xpath for element `mainForm:queryConfigure:fetchReport`.

```
<span id="mainForm:queryConfigure:j_id18">
<table id="mainForm:queryConfigure:j_id19"
       class="showReportTable" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<input id="mainForm:queryConfigure:fetchReport" type="image"
       src="images/show_report.gif" name="mainForm:queryConfigure:fetchReport"/>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</span>
```

I tried

```
selenium.click("//input[@id='mainForm:queryConfigure:fetchReport'][@type='image'][@src='images/show_report.gif']");
```

and

```
selenium.click("//input[@id='mainForm:queryConfigure:fetchReport']");
```

One more case:

```
<div class="tabUnselectedText" align="center">
<a href="javascript:renderPage('mainForm:consoleBeanId.1','Notifications', 'notifications.faces');">Notifications</a>
</div>
```

Comment: /html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/form[@id='mainForm']/div[@id='mainForm:j_id_jsp_maintemplatejspjsp103']/div[@id='mainForm:body']/table[@id='mainForm:analysisSelectTable']/tbody/tr[3]/td/table[@id='mainForm:analysisSelectMainTable']/tbody/tr/td/span[@id='mainForm:queryConfigure:j_id18']/table[@id='mainForm:queryConfigure:j_id19']/tbody/tr/td/input[@id='mainForm:queryConfigure:fetchReport']


this is the xpath collected from xpather plugin. This does not work with selenium RC

Answer (score 0):

Id and name attribute values are acceptable locators for method `click`. See [locating elements](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_selenese_commands.html#locating-elements) in the documentation.

```
selenium.click('mainForm:queryConfigure:fetchReport');
```